# Azure Pipeline - Sql150DatabaseSchemaProvider

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am currently trying to deploy a SQL Server 2019 DACPAC to a server in Azure Pipelines. Now I could run the build earlier when I was targeting SQL Server 2016 (*Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider*). But I have since upgraded the SQL Server to 2019 and need to use the 2019 provider (*Sql150DatabaseSchemaProvider*).

So I changed the target platform to SQL Server 2019 or Azure SQL Database Managed Instance in Visual Studio. Pushed my changes, the build worked and created the DACPAC. Now when it comes to the release and it needs to deploy the DACPAC I am running into the following error:

`2020-04-24T11:42:53.5854889Z Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql150DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.`

The YAML for the deploy is as follows:

```
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Deploy Database'
  inputs:
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/XXX.XXXXX/Database/XXX.XXXXX.Database.dacpac'
    TargetMethod: connectionString
    ConnectionString: '$(DBUpgradeConnectionString)'
```